# How to restart this program

Tags: for-loop, text-files, restart

So this is my code that works fine alone.....

```
def program():
   for x in y:
      for g in t: 
          if x == g:
             return True

    return False 

print ("Welcome")
y = input(" enter...").lower().split()

with open("pro.txt", "r")as file:
lines = file.readlines()

o = False

for line in lines:
item = line.split("-")
t = item[0].split()
a = item[1]

if program():
    print (a)

    o = True 

if o == False:
print ("sorry")
```

I did ask this question before, but I didn't explain well enough. so the problem I have here is that I do not know how to restart this program one of my attempts was this.....

```
def restart():
answer = ''
while answer not in ('y','n'):
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')

if answer == 'y':
    return program()

if answer == 'n':
    return False

else:
    return None    
while restart() == True:
program()
```

This code is at the bottom
however this didn't seem to work as I answer the question with 'y' or 'n' didn't seem to work as when I answer the program ends. so my question is why doesn't it work and how will you make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Still have no clue on how to fix this.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is this Python? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the "[edit]" link under the post. Thank you.